# Migrate JIRA to Redmine

Tags: jira, redmine

I would like to migrate JIRA information to Redmine, is it possible to import with xml ?
Cause i export Jira's information in a XML file and i need to import this in Redmine.

Regards,

Baalane

Answer (score 0):

I don't have first-hand experience with JIRA-to-Redmine migration but I have administered Redmine and I don't think there is build-in way to import Redmine data via XML files in standard Redmine.

There used to be a [Redmine plugin](https://www.redmine.org/plugins/jira2redmine) to do the JIRA migration via the API but the [download link](http://rozwiazaniait.com/index.php/jira-to-redmine-importer/) is dead and has been at least since 01-01-2021 (see https://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/39994 and https://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/39958).

So to import XML files you could use tools, like these:

- https://www.redmine.org/issues/1385 (rake script with XML input, which ended up in https://github.com/Kulgar/jira2redmine)
- https://github.com/hacpaka/jira2redmine (migrate users, project, issues via XML)

I have not used the above tools and cannot comment on them.

You can find some more ideas about this migration in this post: [Can I import Jira tickets into redmine](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/17752/can-i-import-jira-tickets-into-redmine).